# MySql Union of two result sets

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two result sets as below. I would like a merged result with NULLs of first result replaced with values from second result set.

[Edit - added for clarity]

First result set is actual data as collected and aggregated by month. If you see the rows of first table are every month. They come from another table that collects historical data. The second result set are forecast value for next month. I want to be able to show actual values where available and fill-in with forecasted values where 'null'.

```
mysql> SELECT sf.date, sf.col1, sf.col2, sf.col3, sf.col4, sf.col5, sf.col6, sf.col7, sf.col8 FROM sf_table AS sf order by sf.date desc limit 3;              
+------------+------+-------+----------+-------+---------+------+------+--------+                       
| date       | col1 | col2  | col3     | col4  | col5    | col6 | col7 | col8   |
+------------+------+-------+----------+-------+---------+------+------+--------+ 
| 2015-12-01 | 5.00 | 48.20 |     NULL |  NULL |    NULL | 2.24 | 0.24 |   NULL | 
| 2015-11-01 | 5.00 | 48.60 | 12288.50 | 69344 | 1282.00 | 2.26 | 0.12 | 238.11 | 
| 2015-10-01 | 5.00 | 50.10 | 12201.40 | 69584 | 1161.00 | 2.07 | 0.12 | 238.04 |
+------------+------+-------+----------+-------+---------+------+------+------

mysql> SELECT mai.date, mai.col1, mai.col2, mai.col3, mai.col4, mai.col5, mai.col6, mai.col7 , mai.col8 FROM vw_month_ahead as mai order by ai.date desc limit 3;       
+------------+----------+-----------+--------------+--------------+-------------+----------+----------+------------+ 
| date       | col1     | col2      | col3         | col4         | col5        | col6     | col7     | col8       |
+------------+----------+-----------+--------------+--------------+-------------+----------+----------+------------+ 
| 2016-01-29 | 4.951949 | 47.433569 | 12379.161917 | 69778.974145 | 1369.281614 | 2.283758 | 0.229009 | 238.427982 |
+------------+----------+-----------+--------------+--------------+-------------+----------+----------+------------+
```

How can I get the below?

```
+------------+----------+-----------+--------------+--------------+-------------+----------+----------+------------+
| date       | col1     | col2      | col3         | col4         | col5        | col6     | col7     | col8       |
+------------+----------+-----------+--------------+--------------+-------------+----------+----------+------------+
| 2015-12-01 | 5.00     | 48.20     | 12379.161917 | 69778.974145 | 1369.281614 | 2.24     | 0.24     | 238.427982 |
+------------+----------+-----------+--------------+--------------+-------------+----------+----------+------------+
```

PLEASE NOTE: Col3, Col4, Col5 and Col8 are coming from the second result set (vw_month_ahead) where as others are the topmost row of first result set (sf_table).

Comment: This isn't very clear. Why should that row from `mai` and not some other row be used to fill the gaps in `sf`? What's the relation between the tables?

Comment: @EdCottrell, no particular reason. It can be the other way around. Typically only first result set has NULL columns. The second result set will always have a value. The only relationship is that number of columns and their names are same.

Comment: @Stidgeon, only one result row but if there are more that is OK. I can then get "order by date desc limit 1" or something like that.

Comment: But what's the relationship between the rows? Simply the order in which they appear with your ORDER BY clause? There's no obvious relation, which makes it very unclear what you are trying for.

Comment: @EdCottrell, to be precise - first result set is actual data as collected and aggregated by month. If you see the rows of first table are every month. They come from another table that collects historical data. The second result set are forecast value for next month. I want to be able to show actual values where available and fill-in with forecasted values where 'null'. Does that help explain?

Comment: That makes much more sense; thanks.

Comment: Ok, so, you need the value from mai.* with what relationship, exactly? Are you looking for where mai.date is the first row larger than sf.date? Or some aggregate of the values in mai.date for the next month after sf.date?

Comment: "mai" always returns only one row as it is forecast values for next month. So , yes - "mai.date" will always be greater than "max(sf.date)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
SELECT
      sf.date
    , coalesce(sf.col1,mai.col1)
    , coalesce(sf.col2,mai.col2)
    , coalesce(sf.col3,mai.col3)
    , coalesce(sf.col4,mai.col4)
    , coalesce(sf.col5,mai.col5)
    , coalesce(sf.col6,mai.col6)
    , coalesce(sf.col7,mai.col7)
    , coalesce(sf.col8,mai.col8)
FROM sf_table AS sf
left join vw_month_ahead AS mai 
  on sf.date = date_add(date_add(mai.date,INTERVAL -(day(mai.date)-1) DAY),INTERVAL -1 MONTH)
ORDER BY
      sf.date DESC limit 3;
```

which would present data from sf_table if available, if not then present data from vw_month_ahead.

[EDIT] Note that the join condition proposed above reduces the date to first of the month, then deducts one month. e.g. 2016-01-29 becomes 2016-01-01 and then it becomes 2015-12-01 so that it may be aligned to the sf_table date.

You could return zero if no data is available from either table like this:

```
SELECT
      sf.date
    , coalesce(sf.col1,mai.col1,0)
    , coalesce(sf.col2,mai.col2,0)
...
```

Comment: Works like a champ for my purposes. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Since the comments describe `mai` as only containing one row, you would do something like this:

```
SELECT sf.date, IFNULL(sf.col1, mai.col1) col1, IFNULL(sf.col2, mai.col2) col2, ...
FROM sf_table AS sf
LEFT JOIN vw_month_ahead AS mai
ORDER BY sf.date DESC;
```

This query joins the two tables together and, where the values in `sf` are null, uses the value from `mai` (which could be null, if there were no rows in mai). Note that you're going to have to repeat the IFNULL() column descriptions for each column you wish to merge in this manner. It's tedious, yes, but it'll work.

If you needed to extend this to multiple tables, then you could use `COALESCE()` instead of `IFNULL()`

Comment: Would this work even though the dates are not same? One is 2015-12-01 and the other 2016-01-29.

Comment: ahh... I missed that detail. That would change the query somewhat. What exactly is the relationship between the sf and mai? There needs to be a describable relationship between the two to join the two tables together, but the query is probably salvageable once that's determined.

Comment: Sorry, I realized that my question did not have enough details. So I have edited and added details. Please see above.